# Executable files, office, mathematical equations

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am student of software engineering, so for those purposes, I need some software to run it.

I have to create c++ programs and I have got a development environment. But don't know where and how will I run executable files of .exe in terminal, as I use to run them through command prompt.

Second thing is that, which software will be use to run in place of word and excel?

For mathematical subjects, I use MathType, will this software work? And if not, then what can I use to type mathematical equations, like fractions, squareroots, derivatives etc.

And which software can be use to create flow charts and graphs?

Comment: I'm not sure about MathType as I've not use it but you're able to use you MS Office package using `wine` to execute `.exe` files. Which version of MS Office are we talking about?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are willing to accept a new toolset, rather than using the old tools through [wine](http://www.winehq.org/), a change to Ubuntu doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

I'm sure there are lots of competent people here who can give advice on cross-compilation in Eclipse (or any other IDE) under Ubuntu.

LibreOffice with its modules (Writer, Calc, Impress) is a good replacement for MS Office (MSO). LibreOffice Writer comes with an Equation Editor, comparable to that in MSO. The latter is a stripped-down version of MathType.

If you want high-quality, publication-ready math typing, graphs, etc., please consider to give [LaTeX](http://www.tug.org/begin.html) a chance.

Comment: Dear Sir, you have given good answer but, I didn't understood what is wine and in the end you said to give latex a change, what is latex? I'm totally new.